# Thunderbird unread message count not displayed

Tags: thunderbird, gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock

Thunderbird doesn't show the unread counter on its symbol in the dock for me on Ubuntu 18.04 and 18.10 (both with gnome).
Is that normal? If not, does anybody know what the problem could be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it!

I was missing the `thunderbird-gnome-support` package which is not installed with the `thunderbird` package by default, it must be installed explicitly. Having it installed, my thunderbird dock icon shows the unread counter as expected.

Answer (score 1):

**Update 2023 Feb**
With [dash-to-dock](https://github.com/micheleg/dash-to-dock) you get a message counter. The [newest version v79](https://github.com/micheleg/dash-to-dock/releases/tag/extensions.gnome.org-v79) adds notifications emblems, great!
Maybe you still need some of the packages mentioned below (e.g libindicator7, libindicator3-7, thunderbird-gnome-support).

**Ubuntu 18.04**
Somehow it **worked after a new install of Ubuntu 18.04** and it would have probably if I have not changed something.
There is a discussion around this topic on [Mozilla Bugzilla, **please leave your comments**.](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1482674)

**Make sure following is in place** to get the new email/message badge/counter for the Thunderbird Icon (Ubuntu Dock, Dash-To-Dock):
**1. Ensure that** **indicator support is installed** on your system (packages libindicator7 and libindicator3-7 [as mentioned here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/438082)), it is most likely already installed. If not, install them, e.g. in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install libindicator7 libindicator3-7
```

This will enable your system to **receive** indicator messages.
2. In Thunderbird open Tools → Add-ons: **Ensure that the add-on/extension named "Messaging Menu and Unity Launcher Integration" is enabled** (it should be installed by default - I disabled as I thought Ubuntu 18.04 has no Unity anymore but Gnome but it also works with Gnome).
3. **Ensure `thunderbird-gnome-support` package is installed** as [mentioned](https://askubuntu.com/a/1131245/30631) by [InvisibleShadowGost](https://askubuntu.com/users/832125/invisibleshadowghost) (it should be installed by default as well).
4. Restart Thunderbird and maybe logout/in as well.

**Other possibilities** to get the **functionality** to see the unread messages:

- [FireTray](https://github.com/Ximi1970/FireTray): Thunderbird 60 tray icon (js-ctypes version of Firetray)
- [systray-x](https://github.com/Ximi1970/systray-x): SysTray-X: A system tray extension for Thunderbird 68+.   Needs both the add-on AND the companion app installed to work.

Answer (score 1):

I used [birdtray](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2018/10/birdtray-thunderbird-tray-icon-with-new.html), which can be installed with the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install birdtray -y
```

Birdtray features:

1. Thunderbird tray icon with unread email counter
2. The tray icon can flash (blink) when new emails are received. with configurable blinking speed
3. Configurable accounts / mail folder for which it should check for new emails
4. Configurable unread count font colors for different email accounts
   Can hide and restore the Thunderbird window by double clicking on the tray icon or from the tray icon context menu
5. Can automatically start Thunderbird when launching Birdtray and close
6. Thunderbird when exiting the tray icon
7. Configurable tray icon (for both regular and unread icon)
8. Can detect if Thunderbird was accidentally closed
9. Snooze new email notifications for a predefined amount of time
10. Allows adding pre-configured email templates to the tray for quick access (New Email tab in Birdtray - requires restarting Birdtray after adding new pre-configured emails)